# Obtianing output of NeurophStudio - import error (java)

Tags: java, import, neural-network, image-recognition

I am trying to abtain the output (for example: cat: 0,988; dog: 0.012) from NeurophStudio using java. The neural net recognises the images well. I found the code below. I get errors in the first two import lines. Does anyone know where I can find/download these packages? I searched through all my directories already and didn't find it.

```
import org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork; // ! error
import org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.ImageRecognitionPlugin; // ! error
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageRecognitionSample {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // load trained neural network saved with Neuroph Studio (specify some existing neural network file here)
    NeuralNetwork nnet = NeuralNetwork.load("Neural Networks/Iconnet25-8.nnet"); // load trained neural network saved with Neuroph Studio
    // get the image recognition plugin from neural network
    ImageRecognitionPlugin imageRecognition = (ImageRecognitionPlugin)nnet.getPlugin(ImageRecognitionPlugin.class); // get the image recognition plugin from neural network

    try {
         // image recognition is done here (specify some existing image file)
        HashMap<String, Double> output = imageRecognition.recognizeImage(new File("testimage.png"));
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

source : http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html

I found the package code here : https://github.com/neuroph/neuroph/tree/master/neuroph-2.9/Core/src/main/java/org/neuroph/core 
Problem: this is not downloadable and I will probably need multiple files/entire package.

Does anyone have experience with this? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

download neuroph.jar
then locate it to your project
like this
right click on your project
properties
Libraries
add jar/folder
then show the path where you put the neuroph.jar

hope it will help you!!!!

Comment: here is the link to download neuroph.jar

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ainalyzer/files/lib/Neuroph/neuroph.jar/download?use_mirror=master&download=&failedmirror=kent.dl.sourceforge.net

Comment: It's better to edit your answer than to comment on your own answer. Also, try to pay attention to punctuation and formatting. Thank you and welcome to StackOverflow.